# SQLite C API: running transaction, responding to errors

Tags: sqlite, transactions

I'm fairly new to SQLite, and I'm just trying to get my head around running transactions (with the C API). In this case, I just need to run two consistent updates on two tables.

The easiest approach seems to be the one in [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitec/). You just `sqlite3_exec` a single combined sequence of commands, which start with `BEGIN` and end with `COMMIT`. So, you never do a `ROLLBACK`, and you presumably rely on SQLite automatically rolling back if it encounters an error.

The problem is that the section on handling transaction errors in [the manual](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) is fairly complex, and it's not obvious to me that this is a good approach. The doc also suggests manually rolling back.

The next approach would be to exec a single `BEGIN`, and then run each statement individually, checking for errors, and then finally run a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. Is this actually any better, or is it just busywork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlite3_exec()` will abort in the first error encountered, an most errors do not result in an automatic rollback.

You should execute the BEGIN first, then do all the stuff inside the transaction, then end the transaction with either COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

In the case of ROLLBACK, you might just ignore any errors. Either the transation already was rolled back, or there is nothing you could do anyway.